# Why aren't the images of the first two instances of WhitePawn() displayed?

Tags: python, oop, kivy

Here's my Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


class WhitePawn():
    def __init__(self):
        self.source='whitepawn.png'
        
class CubeWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self,color,id,piece,**kwargs):
        self.color=color
        self.id=id
        self.piece=piece
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.piece:
            self.img=Image(source='whitepawn.png')
            self.add_widget(self.img)
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x,touch.y):
            print(self.id,self.pos)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)    
class New_Board(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.board=[]
        self.theme=None
        self.gen_board()
    def gen_board(self):
        a=[(WhitePawn(),1,1),(WhitePawn(),2,2),(WhitePawn(),3,3)]
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                color=(0,1,0,1) if (i+j)%2!=0 else (1,1,1,1)
                for k in a:
                    if (k[1],k[2])==(i,j):
                        cube=CubeWidget(color,(i,j),k[0])
                        self.board.append((k[0],cube))
                    else:
                        cube=CubeWidget(color,(0,0),None)
                self.add_widget(cube)
class MyChessApp(App):
    def build(self):
        board=New_Board()
        return board
           
MyChessApp().run()
```

only the last whitepawn instance is displaying the image none other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is flawed. Your `for k in a:` loop is printing every square of the board thrice.

Here is a short reproduceable example of what you are currently doing.

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        for k in a:
            if (k[0], k[1]) == (i, j):
                print((i, j), 'printed piece')
            else:
                print((i, j), 'printed blank')
```

For the position `(1, 1)` you will see:

```
(1, 1) printed piece
(1, 1) printed blank
(1, 1) printed blank
```

As you see, `(3, 3)` is the only one where the piece is in final position it checks. That is why it's the one that survives.

```
(3, 3) printed blank
(3, 3) printed blank
(3, 3) printed piece
```

A simple fix would be to utilize the `else` in your final `for` loop to print the blank position if the `for` loop didn't yield any results for pieces.

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        for k in a:
            if (k[0], k[1]) == (i, j):
                print((i, j), 'printed piece')
                break
        else:
            print((i, j), 'printed blank')
```

However, some people shy away from the `else` on `for` loops since it's a less utilized portion of the language.

If you want something that works without using the `else`, this should work.

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        piece = None
        for k in a:
            if (k[0], k[1]) == (i, j):
                piece = k
        if piece is not None:
            print((piece[0], piece[1]), 'printed piece')
        else:
            print((i, j), 'printed blank')
```